# AzureOpenAI not Available in Langchain

Tags: python, pip, package, anaconda, langchain

I am trying to use the `langchain` package in `Python` to interact with `Azure Open AI`.
In my personal laptop, once I run `pip install langchain` I am successfully able to import using `from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI`.
But when I perform the same steps in my office laptop it gives me an `ImportError: cannot import name 'AzureOpenAI' from langchain.llms (C:\...\lib\site-packages\langchain\llms\__init__.py)`

I opened this `__init__.py` file and they are different in my personal laptop and my office laptop, and when I look for the keyword "`AzureOpenAI`" there is none in my office laptop.
Why are the `langchain` installations different between my personal and company laptop even though I ran the same command `pip install langchain`? Is there a way to make it work in my office laptop?